# How to modify the lotus notes hyperlinks from Sharepont Search

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, lotus-notes

I'm able to crawl lotus notes databases and have the results appear in my search results using sharepoint search server.

The problem I'm having, though, is that the results contain links that send me to a blank lotus notes document.

In sharepoint I have defined my content source as `C:\lotus\notes\databases\` where all of my databases are stored.  After a full crawl I can do a search and my results appear this way:

```
notes://domino_server/database.nsf/($defaultview)/<document_id>
```

I've narrowed my issue down to being the `($defaultview)` included in the link.

My questions are, where is this value coming from, and how can I change the results and links being provided?

Some of my research has stated that I want to modify the html web part, but I have no idea how to do that or where to do that.

Comment: Two questions: First, are you saying that literally, the text string "($defaultview)" is appearing in your URL? Second, what software is doing the crawl of the Notes database? I'm not aware of searching Notes databases being a feature of Sharepoint, so I'm thinking you've got a 3rd party product installed -- but I'm not sure. Also (oops! that makes three questions), what database are you searching, and do you have the ability to look at the database's design? It's actually possible that the database was deliberately built to show no results when searched this way.

Comment: @RichardSchwartz yes, that is what is appearing in my URL.  Microsoft sharepoint is the software doing the crawl.  It has a built in lotus notes connector - there is no 3rd party software outside of sharepoint.  I do have the ability to look at the database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set one view to "[default view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_DEFAULT_VIEWS.html&resultof=%22default%22%20%22view%22%20)" in your Notes database. It works like an index of all documents in database.

Comment: Interesting... so because it cannot find a `defaultview` it is just redirecting me to blank document?